# couldn't get model in action on post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strongly typed view which has text fields and a submitted link. After editing data I press link and try to submit form. Placing a break point I am able to see control comes to action; modle is not null but all of its properties are always null, not sure where I m doing wrong. My tiny view code is:

```
@model BL.Model.Speaker
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(s => @Model.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(s => @Model.Email)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "All");
}
```

and my controller action is:

```
 public ActionResult All(Speaker model){   
            return View(database.Speakers.FirstOrDefault());
        }
```

Help please

Comment: why down voted ? whats wrong with this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your button from ActionLink to a submit button like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "All");
```

By

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Also change your Action to recieve the data by post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult All(Speaker model)
{   
    return View(database.Speakers.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Comment: 1. Yes, Actually an action link is only anchor witch by default and only redirects by get, 2. No that I know but you can create your own html helper to define a submit button

Comment: remember to accept the question if you consider that solves your problem